# filling colors to different HTML shapes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am applying some images in html code as background image of a div. The image dimensions can change as per user's requirement and images can be of any shape (for example a cloud or a callout or a balloon ). All the applied images are transparent.

Now I want to apply colors to these shapes. If I write background-color to the div / span tag it covers the entire div and I cannot use canvas because image dimensions change.

Is there any way to do it?

**Code:**

```
<div style="background-color:blue;height:400px; width:400px;background-size: 100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url('cloud7.png'); position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; height:400px; width:400px;" /> 

</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your existing code? Will help give you a better answer

Comment: <div style="background-color:blue;height:400px; width:400px;background-size: 100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-image: url('cloud7.png'); position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; height:400px; width:400px;" />
</div>

Comment: I don't want the corners to be colored by the color, the color should curve like the image

Comment: I don't understand what exactly your problem/question is. In what way you you want to apply colors? Do you have example images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use masks for this. Unfortunately, they're currently only [supported in Webkit browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks).

```
<div style="background-color:blue;height:400px; width:400px; background-size:100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat; -webkit-mask: url('cloud7.png'); position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; height:400px; width:400px;" /> 

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .... Is there any way to do it for mozilla also and if not then at least prevent that attribute to be applied there?